# Lost iPhone- how Find my Phone works?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

My son thinks he lost his iPhone whilst out cycling yesterday-he had no data til he got new months allowance which started today- this morning on find my phone it showed at house but we can’t find anywhere- does it show last place it was in when it had WiFi or is it still here now?- have ripped House apart! Thx

Comment: Find My iPhone has a feature where you can make the iPhone searched for emit a noticeable submarine 'ping' sound. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

If your iPhone status is green (online), it's still connected to your home WIFI. If the status is gray, it's showing you the last visible location. You can even see the time and date of that last location.

If your data plan renews today, it should setup automatically. That said, if the phone was lost whilst cycling and is still up and running, you could see the actual location (based on cellular data).

Based on this, I presume you can find it at home: Open Find My iPhone again, **there is a button to make it ring**.

Comment: The "make it ring" option has saved my day more than once :)

Comment: @nohillside yeah, me too :) (edited spelling)